# Comparing values in two dataframes and generate report if difference is greater set point

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 data frames ( master and slave)　looks like below.

```
# Master 
   C   D    E    F   G
0  5  44  4.0   33  22
1  1   0  4.5  565  11


# Slave
   C   D    E      F   G
0  5  44  4.0   33.0  22
1  1   4  6.5  562.5  10
```

Expected results( highlight those cells where difference is > 1)

```
   C   D    E      F   G
0  5  44  4.0   33.0  22
1  1   4  6.5  562.5  10
```

Where  `4`, `6.5`, `562.5` are highlighted

[Picture attached for better understanding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAHp4.jpg)

I would like to compare two data frames and would like to highlight the cells where the difference exceed the `SET VALUE( >1)` in a newly created data frame. SET value=1 is constant for entire data frame.
Please note difference should be based on Absolute value. i.e `ABS( master-  slave)`

I would like to use the numpy np.isclose function to achieve my goal.

This should happen for bigger data frame with 200 rows and 300 columns.
Data frame displayed here is small for better understanding.

- Cell : `D2` : highlight is required since `(D2_MASTER) -(D2_Slave)= 0- 4 = -4`
- Cell : `E2` : highlight is required since `(E2_MASTER) -(E2_Slave)= 4.5- 6.5 = -2`
- Cell : `F2` : highlight is required since `(F2_MASTER) -(F2_Slave)= 565- 562.5.5 = 2.5`
- Cell : `G2` : NO highlight since `(G2_MASTER) -(G2_Slave)=11- 10 = 1` (should not be highlighted since difference is within the limit)

I just started coding in python and using pandas on my own and I admit I am a bit lost.

Thanks for reading all this and thanks in advance for any suggestions and feedback. !

Code

```
for ind,row in dfmaster.iterrows():
    print(row)
    (dfmaster.iloc())=np.isclose ( (dfmaster.iloc())  , (dfmaster.iloc())  , atol=1)#.any()
```

Comment: I am sorry , Data frame is not properly displayed , so kindly request you to check the image link, to have clear picture of the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `style.format`:

```
def highlight_error(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.sub(slave).abs() > 1, 'background-color:red', ''),
                        df.index, df.columns)

master.style.apply(highlight_error, axis=None)
```

On Jupyter notebook you would get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang, it is working perfectly fine. thanks a lot